# I'm getting error cannot find namespace "PowerBI"

Tags: javascript, css, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

**I'm getting error cannot find namespace "PowerBI"**

I'm new to javascript and i was trying this:
Create a dialog box class for your dialog box. The initialState parameter in openModalDialog is passed to the dialog contractor upon its creation. Use the initialState object to pass parameters to the dialog box, in order to affect its behavior or appearance.

The dialog code can use these IDialogHost methods:

IDialogHost.setResult(result:object) - The dialog code returns a result object that will be passed back to its calling visual.
IDialogHost.close(actionId: DialogAction, result?:object) - The dialog code can programmatically close the dialog and provide a result object back to its calling visual.

```
 " import DialogConstructorOptions = powerbi.extensibility.visual.DialogConstructorOptions;
```

import DialogAction = powerbi.DialogAction;

export class DatePickerDialog {
static id = "DatePickerDialog";

```
constructor(options: DialogConstructorOptions, initialState: object) {
    const host = options.host;
    
    // … dialog rendering implementation …
    
    myCalender.onValueChange((currentValue) => {
        pickedDate = currentValue.toLocaleDateString()
        host.setResult({ date: pickedDate });
    });

    myCalender.handleConfirm( () => {
        host.close(DialogAction.Close, {date: pickedDate});
    })
}
```

}        "
This was my code.